# ImageCodecException was thrown resolving an image codec

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am using `1.27.0-4.0.pre` sdk version to my flutter pwa. Before upgrading I used `1.24.0-10.2.pre` sdk version. in 1.24.0-10.2.pre version everything was good and I don't have any problem is showing svg image with `Image.network`. But now When I launch my pwa None of my Image is shown ?

[image]

This read squarer appear instead of image . And I get this error on console:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following ImageCodecException was thrown resolving an image codec:
Failed to decode image data.
Image source: http://localhost:33033/assets/svgs/splash.svg

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 236:49      throw_
lib/_engine/engine/canvaskit/image.dart 102:7                                     createDefault
lib/_engine/engine/canvaskit/skia_object_cache.dart 141:41                        new
lib/_engine/engine/canvaskit/image.dart 92:3                                      decodeFromBytes
lib/_engine/engine/canvaskit/image.dart 75:53                                     <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 324:14  _checkAndCall
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 329:39  dcall
dart-sdk/lib/html/dart2js/html_dart2js.dart 37283:58                              <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1370:13                                              _rootRunUnary
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1265:19                                              runUnary
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1170:7                                               runUnaryGuarded
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1207:26                                              <fn>

Image provider: NetworkImage("assets/svgs/splash.svg", scale: 1)
Image key: NetworkImage("assets/svgs/splash.svg", scale: 1)
```

When I open `http://localhost:33033/assets/svgs/splash.svg` on chrome, this image exist and is loaded. What is a problem?

Comment: SVGs are not supported by flutter.

Comment: In the `1.24.0-10.2.pre` version It's work and I don't have any problem @ChristopherMoore

Comment: See my answer..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SVGs are *not* supported by Flutter by default. If it worked in the past, you were likely using the HTML web renderer where you can get away with using SVG a little bit, but it's not made to do that so there are issues with it.

I see that you're now using the CanvasKit renderer, which likely treats images differently than the HTML renderer and removes any possibility of using SVGs.

You can use the [`flutter_svg`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg) package and use **only** the CanvasKit renderer to possibly reliably use SVGs.

Comment: I remove `Image.network` and I use `flutter_svg` and svg is shown. But other browser can show svg in this way?  @ChristopherMoore

Comment: @CyrustheGreat Could you rephrase that question? It wasn't quite clear. Are you asking if all browsers support this?

Comment: Yes@ChristopherMoore

Comment: @CyrustheGreat I can't say **all**, but I would guess most major desktop and mobile browsers. If flutter web is supported, this SVG is probably support assuming you're using only the CanvasKit renderer.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this issue by seen this video
"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U0Ez4CS6frc".

option 1:   "flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html"

option2:  in the Andriod Studio application go to : Run -> Edit Configuration.  in the Arguments type inputbox put this line
"--web-renderer html"

[ here is the screen shot of option2 ]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDB8I.png